# Pivot Table column that is the difference of 2 columns in the previous row

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I need to add a custom column to a PivotTable whose value is the difference between  values under two columns in the previous row. I tried adding a Calculated Field but I don't know how to reference the previous row in the formula bar:

For example:

[Pivot Table structure and Pivot Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9gd5.png)

Value of Reduced Inventory column should be the difference between the Reduced Inventory and No. of requests columns in the previous row. For the first row, the Reduced Inventory column should be equal to the On-hand Inventory. 
How do I get this output?

Comment: I think you're example is wrong. If I'm understanding it Column C calculation for **row 2** would be: 7 (column B) minus/- 5 (column A of previous row) equals 2 yet you have it as 1?

Comment: Hi @Ram Sidharth,,, I hope U have Column headers,,, if yes then it can be use as fields,, for further calculations,, (calculated Field),,, U can find them in Field box left below in Calculated dialogue,,, better share screen shot of Pivot Table !

Comment: @RajeshS - I've added a screenshot to the question to make it clearer. Let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: @RamSidharth, considering Screen Shot, suppose U want difference between `No Of Req` and `On Hand Inv`,, then for calculated field you may use  `=No Of Req-On Hand Inv`,, Seems U r using Power Pivot then U may take this to `Data Model` & apply same Formula there for New column using the `DAX method`!

Comment: @RajeshS - yea but calculated field is =No of Req (of previous row) - OnHand Inventory (of previous row) : both values need to come from the previous row, not the same row

Comment: ,,, **Cont,,** what U have tried as Reduced inventory is like `38-13 = 25` & `25-13 = 12` means subtracting constant with values get changing,, in Excel somehow is manageable but in PT & even DAX is not looking possible and in the first Row how U r getting `38` is a mystery !! Better [Edit] your post & do meaningful (*add some source data along with expected output*) corrections to avoid Down vote.